# Can I use HM Hud to show aggregate stats of players?

Tags: holdem-manager

I'm grinding a few tables at micro stakes and it would be really helpful if I had the lifetime stats for each player at my table as opposed to just the stats starting from when I sat down.

Is this possible for me to see the entire history of stats for each player at my table??

Comment: By "entire history" do you mean every hand that player has played, or do you mean every hand that you have played with that player? My guess is that your HUD is already showing you the stats for every hand you've played with that player (that's been imported by the app).  In PokerTracker you can easily change the HUD view between all-time stats and single-session stats for an individual player.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Can you please post your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the gear icon to enter hud options (see the picture) and select "All hands"
[image]